# $T \in A(V)$ is a linear transformation and $q(x) \in F[x]$ such that $q(T) = 0$. Is every root of $q(x)$ in $F$ a characteristic root of $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question from Herstein's Topics in Algebra section 6.2. I'm not able to start attacking the problem at all. I'm not asking for a solution, but general directions on how to proceed will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Think about this: can you "add" more roots to $q(x)$ that aren't characteristic roots of $T$?

Comment: *Hint*: try with linear transformation $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, that is, matrices $1\times 1$, also said multiplication by scalar

Comment: Why don't you start  by constructing some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Try $T=id$ and $q(x)=x^2-1$.

On the other hand, if $q$ has least degree, then it is true.

Answer (score 1):

Write $A=\{q\in F[x]|\;q(T)=0\}$. As you may know, $A$ consists of all polynomials that are divisible by $m_T(x)$, the minimal polynomial. The important observation regarding your question is that *for every scalar $\lambda\in F$ there is a $q\in A$ such that $q(\lambda)=0$.*

Answer (score 0):

what about the minimal polynomial for $T$. What can you say about that? what is the relation between the minimal polynomial and $q(x)$. Although all the roots maynot be characterestic roots as some friends has already said in the comments and answers, but at least can all the characterestic roots be roots of $q(x)$ too!